# Imagen Background proyecto djgango

Tags: html, css, django

estoy jugando con un proyecto bastante antiguo (django 1.5.12) y no se como establecer una imagen de background para la pantalla principal, no tengo muchos conocimientos en css, de antemano muychas gracias.

adjunto el codigo de mi html: [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

en  coloque una imagen para probar y me la cargar pero desproporcionada y descentrada.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

tengo el css en static/css  y la imagen en static/img
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

asi modifique el html:[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

y este es el app.css[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Hola @JIrenicus, bienvenid@ a Stack Overflow, te sugiero completar el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para que te familiarices con el funcionamiento del lugar y de paso ganar tu primera medalla. También puedes revisar la sección de [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que tus preguntas sean bien recibidas por la comunidad y obtengas respuestas de calidad. Con respecto a tu pregunta, deberías editala y cambiar la imagen del código HTML por texto.

Answer (score 0):

Agrega una hoja de estilos, ejemplo app.css, borra lo que tienes en el html dela imagen de fondo, y agrega esta linea

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="URL DE LA HOJA DE ESTILOS.css">
```

Luego en la hoja de estilos agrega esto:

```css
 body{
  background-image: url("URL DE LA IMAGEN");
  height: 100vh;
 }
```

Y cuéntame que tal te fue.

Comment: lo hice pero aun no me funciona, agregare unas capturas y como tengo distribuidas las carpetas, quizás es por la ruta...

Comment: Intenta agregar el <link rel="stylesheet" href="URL DE LA HOJA DE ESTILOS.css"> en el HEAD

Answer (score 0):

para que la imágen se vea correctamente en todas las resoluciones deberias sustituir tu código:

```
body{
  background-image: url("static/img/joblist.jpg");
  height: 100vh;
}
```

por este:

```
body { 
  background: url("static/img/joblist.jpg") no-repeat center center fixed; 
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
}
```

Ésto lo que hace es cubrir la totalidad del cuerpo de la página según lo grande que sea la ventana del navegador y además es compatible con todos los navegadores.

También como ha dicho Christian, asegúrate de que el "link" está dentro de la cabecera "head" y que la ruta "static/img/joblist.jpg" sea correcta.

Para lo primero, tendrías que ubicar la página maestra o plantilla, ya que "portada.html" es un simple "div" por lo que ahí no te funcionará nunca por mucho que pongas el "link" a tu CSS, debe haber algún fichero que contiene la plantilla de la página (página maestra) o la cabecera, te recomiendo buscar el tag "head" entre los ficheros de tu proyecto con el buscador de tu editor.

Cualquier cosa nos dices.

Comment: ok muchas gracias, lo revisaré!